# com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket (After removing mongodb altogether)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I was given an application after half development, and I had to finish the development, but because of licensing issues, I was asked to remove mongodb and use couchdb instead. Now, I have removed all instances of mongodb connections in the code, removed mongo connection properties from application.properties, but I still keep getting the following error when I start the spring  application.

> 2022-01-21 15:58:14.043  INFO  --- [localhost:27017] o.m.d.cluster                            : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
> at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
> ... 4 more

My pom.xml looks like this, I can't remove mongo dependency from it because still using bson document class.

> 

4.0.0

```
<hidden>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<hidden>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <hidden>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.ektorp</groupId>  
        <artifactId>org.ektorp</artifactId>  
        <version>1.4.4</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lightcouch</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightcouch</artifactId> 
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <hidden>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is my application.properties

```
spring.data.couchdb.host=localhost
spring.data.couchdb.port=5984
spring.data.couchdb.authentication-database=hidden
spring.data.couchdb.username=hidden
spring.data.couchdb.password=hidden
spring.data.couchdb.database=hidden
spring.data.couchdb.uri=http://localhost:5984
# JWT configuration
jwt.secret = authsecret
jwt.expirationDateInMs=600000
jwt.refreshExpirationDateInMs=600000
```

There are no issues in running the application, but need to remove this error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The code was not hosted on any server. I got the zipped code and first thing I did was remove all this before running the application. Mongodb is not even installed on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this dependency

```xml
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

By default, spring autoconfiguration is kicking-in and trying to open and create connection.

Or the other way is to exclude autoconfiguration from spring application as given below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class SampleApplication{...}
```

I'd suggest to better remove dependency as you have made decision to remove mongodb from application.

Comment: My friend you are a genius! Thank you so much! I can't remove the entire dependency because as I said, using bson documents and some other stuff that is included in mongo dependency, but I added the exclude clause and it is perfect now! I was skeptical about it at first because I had even removed the imports for the classes that we excluded, but I tried and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad, it helped.